# Problem with Error handling change in API Call

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding

I am fairly new to Angular but not to development in general. Doing a personal project to try and learn Angular's capabilities and I am trying to handle an api call to change html code actively. Below I have an example of my code. I am calling the pokemon API and displaying basic info right now, all I am trying to do is make it so the page displays not found if the response returns an error. I just don't know the best way to handle this in Angular and any help is appreciated.

For more clarification I have been able to get the error to pop up, the issue is I don't think it will work correctly until I unsubscribe and I don't know exactly when to do that.

By request: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwchtb

```
Pokemon.Component.HTML
<div class="container-fluid" style="text-align: center">

    Pokemon Name:<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Pokemon">

<button (click)="searchForPokemon()">Search</button>
<div *ngIf="response;else noresponse">
    <p>Name: {{response?.name}}</p>
    Possible Abilities:
    <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let a of response?.abilities">{{a.ability.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    Learnable Moves:
    <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let m of  response?.moves">{{m.move.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<ng-template #noresponse><h3>No Pokemon of that name found</h3></ng-template>
</div>

Pokemon.Component.TS

export class PokemonComponent implements OnInit {
  Pokemon: string = "";
  response: any;
  error: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){
  }
  searchForPokemon(value:string){
    this.http.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + 
    this.Pokemon.toLowerCase())
    .subscribe(
      (response)=> this.response = response,
      (err) => this.error = err)          
  }
```

Comment: Seems good to me, any error occuring in your code ?

Comment: No but I think what is happening is when I run another search for a new Pokemon, even if I type random letters, it will not change anything.

Comment: Would you mind creating a [mcve] of your issue ? You can use https://stackblitz.com, it's an online IDE that is very convenient for learning Angular.

Comment: Added Stack Blitz link.

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to this:

```
<div *ngIf="response && !(error && error.length>0)">
    <p>Name: {{response?.name}}</p>
    Possible Abilities:
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let a of response?.abilities">{{a.ability.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    Learnable Moves:
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let m of  response?.moves">{{m.move.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div *ngIf="error && error.length>0" #noresponse><h3>No Pokemon of that name found</h3></div>
</div>
```

**In your ts file :**

```
Pokemon: string = "";
  response: any;
  error:string="";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){
  }
  searchForPokemon(value:string){
    this.error='';
    this.http.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + this.Pokemon.toLowerCase())
    .subscribe(
      (response)=> {this.response = response},
      (err) => this.error = err.message)          
  }
```

[Here working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-newpoikemonsearcherror)

Comment: i looked at the api it looks like it throws an error when pokemon is not found.so the above logic adds a check for that and displays when there is an error.

Comment: This now shows the error correctly but when I try to search again, it now just stays at the No Pokemon of that name found.

Comment: updated my answer to clear error message when response is found

Comment: Yup that worked! I was playing with the ngIf logic before but it kept giving me errors and was trying to aim for something like this.

Comment: can you mark that as an answer if it resolved your issue.Thanks